# How to pass array to a function as its elements in string forms (Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&')

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to pass the imageSrcs array as its array elements with quotation marks. But it doesn't really work that way. How can I pass an array to a function as its elements in string forms?

The goal is something like this:

`initializeSlider($(".slider-1"), ["data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"]);`

```
<%  for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
  let imageSrcs = [];

  for (let j = 0; j < posts[i].images.length; j++) {
      let imageSrc = '"' + `data:image/${posts[i].images[j].image.contentType};base64, ${posts[i].images[j].image.data.toString('base64')}` + '"';
      imageSrcs.push(imageSrc);
  } %>
  initializeSlider($(".slider-<%= i+1 %>"), <%= imageSrcs %>);

<% } %>
```

[image]

Comment: Your array looks like the following if you were to code it directly`let imageSrcs = ['"data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"', ['"data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"', ['"data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"', ]`; not sure why you think you need to wrap it in quotes.

Comment: `initializeSlider` function accepts array of string values, I'm trying to pass string elements stored inside array `imageSrcs`. @epascarello

Comment: Without the quotation marks, the program gets confused cause of commas, semi colons and slashes etc. @epascarello

Comment: Adding quotation marks is just adding the quotation mark to the string, you are not building a string. You have `var a = '"a"';` when it really should just be `var a = "a";`

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I need the elements to be displayed in quotation marks because the program gets confused. @epascarello

Comment: You said, your array looks like `['"data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"', ['"data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"', ['"data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"', ]`. Where do the open brackets come from, I didn't understand. Shouldn't it be there one open bracket and one closing bracket? @epascarello

Comment: My intention is to this: `initializeSlider($(".slider-1"), ["data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx", "data:xxxxxxxxxxxxx"]);` @epascarello

Comment: I copied the extra `[` by accident.... The `'"' +` and `+ '"'` is what needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

`<%= imageSrcs %>` is designed for inserting strings into HTML, not arrays into JavaScript embedded in HTML.

The safe way to approach this is to:

1. Convert your data structure to JSON (i.e. so it is a string, not an array of arrays of strings)
2. Embed it in a data-* attribute (i.e. HTML not JS embedded in HTML)
3. Loop over it client side

Something along the lines of:

```
<%
const postUrls = posts.map(post => 
  post.images.map(image => 
    `data:image/${image.contentType}};base64,${image.data.toString('base64')}`;
  )
);
%>
<script data-postUrls="<%= JSON.stringify(postUrls) %>">
    const postUrls = JSON.parse(document.currentScript.dataset.postUrls);
    postUrls.forEach((post, index) => {
      initializeSlider(`.slider-${index + 1}`, post);
    })
</script>
```

Note that I haven't tested this code. I don't have time to generate a value for `posts` or build an EJS test environment. You might have to tweak it if I'm made minor errors.

Comment: Whole script was already in `<script>` tags, can they work as nested?

Comment: No, you can't nest `<script>` elements.

Comment: I modified the first part of your code (without the script tag), there were minor mistakes: ```<%
    const postUrls = posts.map(
        post => post.images.map(
            image => `data:image/${image.image.contentType};base64, ${image.image.data.toString('base64')}`
        )
    );
    %>```.
But since it's all inside the script tags I couldn't figure out the work-around. Do you have any other ideas? Thank you btw. @Quentin

Comment: The work around is to restructure your code so that you generate your data structure up front in your EJS, then you generate your HTML (including the `<script>` tags) and drop back into EJS *solely* to insert data into the `data-` attribute.

Answer (score -2):

Try putting quotes around "<%= imageSrcs %>" like so:

```
"<%= imageSrcs %>"
```

Comment: That will probably give you code that compiles, but the generated string will be more-or-less junk.

Comment: It puts quotation marks to edges of the array (one in the beginning one in the end) not the edges of elements.